# How to remove an element from an array passing the key using hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple array like this

```
let myArray = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
```

let's say I want to remove the second element, what I would do is

```
myArray.splice(1, 1);
```

but what if to set this array I am using a hook like this?

```
const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState([]);
```

what is the correct way to remove an element passing its index and possibly reorder all the indexes in order not to have gaps?

Comment: There's no difference in how you remove an element from an array.  Though when updating a state value in React you would want to update it to a new instance of an array, not the same instance but modified.  Have you tried?  What didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

In React, you do not mutate existing state using methods like `.splice`. Instead you will create a *new* state and pass it to `setMyArray`. As an example use, this component will loop over `myArray` and create a clickable <kbd>remove</kbd> button for each element in the array -

```js
function immutableSplice(arr, index, count) {
  return [                      // return *new* array
    ...arr.slice(0, index),     // does not mutate arr
    ...arr.slice(index + count) // does not mutate arr
  ]
}

function MyComponent(props) {
  const [myArray, setMyArray] = React.useState(["", "", ""]);
  const removeElement = index => event =>
    setMyArray(immutableSplice(myArray, index, 1))
  return myArray.map((v, index) =>
    <button key={index} onClick={removeElement(index)}>remove {v}</button>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent/>, document.body)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Immutable state is a principle discipline of the React pattern. Because of this, many libraries exist to help with immutable manipulation of objects and arrays. See Immutable.js and Immer, to name a few.

Comment: this actually removes all the elements starting from index (including index)

Comment: no it doesn't. did you run the demo here on the site? it removes only the items that are clicked.